# Questions about unipotent matrices.

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I have a question about the notation in [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3929). On page 8, the 5-th line from bottom, it is said that $u_J(t)$ denotes the upper triangular unipotent matrix with $t$ in position corresponding to the root $\alpha_J=\sum_{j \in J} \alpha_j$. I don't quite understand this. For example, let $u_J(t)$ in $GL_8$ and $J=\{3,4,6\}$. What is $u_J(t)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think $\alpha_J$ is not a root for your choice of $J$. There are many choices for $J$, for instance $J=\{3,4,5,6\}$ works and $u_J(t)$ is the matrix with 1s on the diagonal, 1 in the 3rd row, 7th column, and 0s elsewhere. Not every sum of roots is a root.

Comment: For type $A$, a (positive) root can be given by a pair of natural numbers, since it will be a sum of adjacent simple roots (so the numbers give the first and last of these). This pair then gives an entry in the matrix by letting the first determine the row and the column be $1$ more than the second.

Comment: Note that then $u_J(t)-I$ is the matrix in the Lie algebra on which the maximal torus acts as the root given by $J$ under conjugation.

Comment: I agree with Tobias that pairs of natural numbers are better for type A (GL, SL, PGL). The paper uses the "J" notation which only works for types A, D, and E.